# Tensorflow Lite Micro - Implementing a CNN for Binary Image Classification on ESP32

Tags: c++, tensorflow, microcontroller, tensorflow-lite, tinyml

I am an Electrical & Electronics Engineer trying to implement a binary image classifier that uses a Convolutional Neural Network in Tensorflow Lite Micro on an ESP32. I have trained a simple model that takes in an RGB image of resolution 1024(height)x256(width) in PNG format and returns an output of either 0 or 1 to label the image into two classes.

I have read Pete Warden's book on TinyML and have completed the following steps as per the guide:

1. Trained a simple binary image classifying CNN in google colab
2. I have normalized the image to improve training performance and have reduced the total number of parameters to 1464.
3. I have saved the model into the saved model format and converted the model to .tflite files
4. Finally I have performed the post-training quantization and generated 4 additional files for Dynamic Range, Float16, Full integer with float fallback, and Full integer only post-training quantized tflite files.
5. I then used xxd to convert these .tflite files into .cc files as mentioned in the book.

My problem right now is even though I have worked quite a bit with microcontrollers as an electrical and electronics engineer and although the book elaborately explains the steps, I'm having difficulty in understanding how to actually deploy the model onto the microcontroller itself in a simple manner. I have been trying to understand the process by referring to the files structure and the various files for the example projects mentioned in the book, but even the simple hello world example has too many files and the code is challenging for a beginner to understand.

I would like to know, how to pass a ~107KB RGB PNG file into the model for inference. I understand that I would need to load the image onto SPIFFS (SPI Flash File Storage) as a PNG itself, otherwise, I would lose the image compression if I tried to convert the image into an array and stored it as a text file as the file would be simply too large for the microcontroller.

Therefore I would like to seek some guidance on how to proceed with the C++ code for deploying the CNN model onto my ESP32 Microcontroller in an easy way.
Any help is appreciated, Thank you in advance.